# How to mock store state in angular 16 using ngxs

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, frontend, ngxs

We introduce store in our ongoing project using **ngxs** I'm unable to mock state that have same service dependencies. Any help would be appreciate.

I have setup one simple example to understand:

```
// State of the store
export class TutorialState {

    constructor() {}

    @Selector()
    static getTutorials(state: TutorialStateModel) {
        return state.tutorials;
    }

    @Action(AddTutorial) 
    add({ getState, patchState }: StateContext<TutorialStateModel>, { payload }: AddTutorial) {
        const state = getState();
        patchState({
            tutorials: [...state.tutorials, payload]
        })
    }

    @Action(RemoveTutorial) 
    remove({ getState, patchState }: StateContext<TutorialStateModel>, { payload }: RemoveTutorial) {
        patchState({
            tutorials: getState().tutorials.filter(a => a.name != payload)
        })
    }
    
}



// spec file of the component
class MockAuthenticationService {
  userSubject = new BehaviorSubject({});
  public get userValue() {
    return this.userSubject?.value||null;
  }
}
fdescribe('ReadComponent', () => {
  let component: ReadComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ReadComponent>;
  let store: Store;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [ReadComponent, NgxsModule.forRoot([TutorialState])],
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: MockAuthenticationService }
      ]
    });

    store = TestBed.inject(Store);
    TestBed.inject(AuthenticationService)
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ReadComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Currently getting this error:
Can't resolve all parameters for TutorialState: (?).

Currently, I try to follow NGXS documentation but I didn't any example for complete store mocking or dependencies in the state:
Share any link will be much appreciated.